# Why do I continue to get merge conflicts?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am in this vicious cycle of wanting to revert some commits to a failing build which tells me that I have merge conflicts before I can revert. So I resolve the merge conflicts, add them, commit them, push them, the build fails and when I try to revert some of the commits, they say I have merge conflicts and its the same merge conflicts.

This is what keeps failing:

[image]

but they are all the same. When I try to remove all of them except the latest one with revert, I get that I have merge conflicts. So I resolve them, add them, commit them, push them and we start all over again.

How do I just delete everything except the last commit? `revert` is not working because it just keeps telling me I have the same merge conflict I resolved in the last commit.

This is the error I get:

```
git revert 8459a53eb21
error: could not revert 8459a53... DCMP-959: added member benefits
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

I performed a `git reset HEAD~3` to go back 3 commits, but now how do I ensure I do not recommit those last three commits and just the one I reset to?

Comment: What is your output of `git status` in the error case?

Comment: You’re still in a merging state. Try aborting.

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName, I added the error I get in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git rebase #gitcommithash` - using `git-rebase` the result is not a new commit into your repository, but a updated Head at your given commit.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

**git-rebase** can be used also for merging one branch into another. ( instead of git merge )

**git-merge** and **git-revert** add a new commit into your repository.

Another possible solution for that is using `git reset`.

`git reset --hard #commithash`

then push your current state into repository with:

`git push --force`